# Yii2:Integrating the html code into yii2 menubar

Tags: yii2

I have this bunch of code that i want to integrate in yii2 & its very lengthy process i want to know which tag are possible to be integrated in yii2. Also i want this code put in layout not to be visible in the index page. How to do that.

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="nav-header">
                        <div class="dropdown profile-element"> <span>
                                <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/img/profile_small.jpg"/>
                            </span>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                                <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold"><?php //echo $model->email_address; ?></strong>
                                    </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">Admin <b class="caret"></b></span> </span> </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                                <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['site/profile'])?>">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?= Url::to('site/contacts')?>">Contacts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?= Url::to('site/mailbox')?>">Mailbox</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="php/processing/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logo-element">
                            Hive
                        </div>

                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span class="nav-label">Layout</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li><a href="<?= Url::to('site/grid-options')?>">Grid options</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?= Url::to('site/boxed-layout')?>">Boxed layout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a target="_blank" href="<?= Url::to('builder/index')?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span class="nav-label">New Data Format</span></a>            
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

I hav converted a little bit.
I am confused between whether to apply menubar, navbar in layout for showing above data or keep it as it is in layout main.php.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 layouts: one including the other.

Your entire website should use 1 layout and your login page should use another layout. To include 1 layout in another you can do the following:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('main.php'); ?>

put the code for your sidebar here
  ...............
    ......

<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Now you have 2 layouts, 1 with the sidebar and 1 without it that you can use for the login.

Comment: P thank you so much for your quick response. I got the answer for one of my probblem my main issue is whether the above code i have given to be converted in yii2 Html tags as for ul & li also mapping is there & for <nav></nav> tag also mapping is there. thing is the css is not getting applied if i convert the code in to yii2 tags.

Comment: I just want to know if i keep the above code as it is in the nav bar then will it cause any problem further?????

Comment: bcoz i have multiple menubars in my project with a lot of css with animation applied on it...

Comment: You do not have to convert the code to yii2, you can leave it as it is if it is fixed.